# CSV Files in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I've been following Paraview's documentation for loading in csv files. I have one loaded in and ready to use, but i'm not entirely happy with the processes they've suggested. As both apply to dots and apply to grid points are both pretty ugly...

I'm using the dataset 'Sally', which as my lecturer suggested is apparently pretty well known (looks like a tornado or something). The dot layout of the data make it look like a tornado, but all the dots are set to one colour... How can i map different colours to different layers of the data?

Thank you

Comment: Could not find the dataset you are talking about. Can you please upload it to any file sharing website ?

Comment: Here's a link to some C code that i have written to generate the dataset in a CSV file. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BFLDlhBWKcoGGPtl-80h82MrY8Njm4NA

Comment: The shared folder is empty. Also what do you mean "generating". Can't you share the csv file ?

Comment: It's quite a large CSV... I will create another csv file with less points (it will still large file), then comment again once it's uploaded

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11gtLMe6M7i-uoS57bx4ABiqYkTfNp22R -- This is a CSV file with not as many points (just so it could upload quickly)

Comment: @MathieuWestphal Hi there, a friend of mine is stuck on a similar problem (we're sharing code), is it possible for you to assist him too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733326/problems-importing-into-paraview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to Open your csv file in ParaView and load it as a Geometry.

- File -> Open -> Select your csv file -> Apply
- Filters -> Tables To Points -> Set X, Y and Z -> Apply

You know have a polydata with a lot of points. If you want to have coloring based on a parameters, you have to compute some data on the dataset, as your csv file does not seem to contain any.

For example :

- Filters -> Elevation -> Z axis -> Apply

Can be what your are looking for.

Comment: Legend, thanks mate. Before i mark your answer as right, how can i achieve something similar to this https://youtu.be/evdaI0gayxg?t=146 - This an example of the Sally dataset (actually my lecturers youtube channel). I can't use Voreen because i'm mac based, but after playing with your suggestion, i'm not sure if i'm able to achieve something similar that illustrate the 'swirl' inside the dataset.

Comment: This is complicated. first you are missing some data to visualize, the kind of "layer" we see in the video are not present in the csv file. Second you would need to convert the points to a volumic dataset using `Filters->ResampleToImage` filter.

Comment: What data is missing? It has the 3 data component positions in space (x, y and z)... Is it missing the time steps?

Comment: Because we were given a function in c that generates the data. It was then my job to finish writing the code and export to a file format that works with the software. I'm pretty sure in the video you watched, that the guy did the same, maybe just exported it to a different format.

Comment: In the video, the data is colored using a data. This data is missing imho. But this is not the place for this discussion.

Comment: That's fair. Is it possible to get your advice by other means such as email? I can show you the code that used to create the data as well as the code that i've built export to a CSV file.

Comment: You can send a mail to the paraview mailing list. You can register here : https://www.paraview.org/mailing-lists/

Comment: I actually registered today, but when i asked a question it was rejected 'because i'm not registered', even thought i am... thanks for your help

Comment: You should have received an email. To confirm your registration